# ArchUnit detects statement as an error - javap

Tags: java

I have such a test that checks if the `shared` package has only interfaces, enums and data classes.

```
package demo

class Phone {
    fun doSomething(arg: Foo) = when(arg) {
        Foo.ABC -> "abc"
        Foo.DEF -> "def"
    }
}

enum class Foo {
    ABC, DEF
}
```

We can see that Kotlin generates an additional synthetic class `Phone$WhenMappings`, and that ArchUnit rule tries to analyze it despite that it makes no sense.

Comment: What is the implementation of `PhoneType`? Enum?

Comment: Can you post the output of `javap -v 'shared/vo/Phone$WhenMappings.class'`?

Answer (score 1):

When we compile the code, the compiler often has to generate some additional synthetic classes or members. This is the case e.g. if using `when` with an enum. In that case the compiler generates an array which maps enum ordinals into execution branches (`when` cases), so `when` can be executed much faster. It has to store this array somewhere, so it synthesizes an additional class for it. In the above case this additional class is named `Phone$WhenMappings`. I believe the Java compiler does a similar thing when using `switch` over an enum.

For this reason we can't expect there will be no "regular" classes in the bytecode. I think your tests should run only against classes that exists explicitly in the source code. I don't know ArchUnit and what are best practices for using it, but maybe you should ignore synthetic classes when running tests?

You will probably see similar problems if using other features of Kotlin, e.g. lambdas. They also require to generate synthetic classes in the bytecode and these classes don't meet your requirements.